# Connection refused when connecting to svc from another pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have simple python application

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:api", "-c", "/app/gunicorn_conf.py" ,"--reload"]
```

where my gunicorn conf file:

```
import multiprocessing
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
timeout = 30
worker_connections = 1000
```

and my deployment YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: localhost:5000/test123:v4
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8000


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: test-pod
```

When I try curl command from test-pod its works file

```
curl -X POST localhost:8000/test
```

but when I try curl from other pods, I get connection refused error. (busybox pod)

```
curl -X POST test-svc:5000/test
```

My kubectl describe svc test-svc

```
Name:              test-svc
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       Selector:  app=test-pod
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.99.11.154
Port:              <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.11:8000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

nslookup works fine

```
Name:   test-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.99.11.154
```

Comment: Does your service work with docker only. outside K8s? just to discard it's not a container/configuration issue.

Comment: Yes it works with docker,

Comment: Just to know if it´s serivce problem, could you try to change `port and targetPort from 5000/http to 8000/8000`? Could you try to use `kubectl expose deployment test-deployment --type=NodePort --name=test-svc`? With nodePort you should be able to curl test-svc:5000/test and cluster-ip:nodeport/test. Could you try it and let me know if that worked?

Comment: where are you running your cluster and nodes?